# Version history of Sharepoint files in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, version-control, sharepoint-2010

I've integrated Sharepoint 2010 in our TFS 2010 - and access the documents via the "Team Explorer" in Visual Studio 2010. I can open and edit all documents (docx e.g.).
But I couldn't access the version history of each item, as I can do it for source code items in the TFS source control.
To do this, I've to open the Sharepoint website, navigate to the document and read the history there.

Are there any options or plugins to get the version history of sharepoint items directly in the Visual Studio?

Thanks,
Konrad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not an option for this without opening the document library in Sharepoint directly.  This is a good idea and you should list it on the UserVoice website for Visual Studio. I think it would make a great Power Tool.
http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio

This is a related request where uses would like to be able to link to a specific version from a TFS Workitem.
http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2052075-easier-method-for-associating-sharepoint-versioned

Mike